# How to bold certain text only in PDFsharp?

Tags: .net, pdfsharp

I'm programming on VB.NET, and making use of the PDFsharp library to create PDF pages according to my program's needs. Now, I need to bold only certain parts of text, but I only know how to bold entire parts of it at once. How do I go about doing this?

Currently, the code I'm using to render words is as follows:

```
Dim graph As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage)
graph.DrawString("Sample Text", New XFont("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), New RectangleF(X, Y, 700, 30), New XStringFormat())
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example above, if you wish to write "Sample Text" with the word "Text" in bold, perform the following;

- Include the MigraDoc+PDFsharp NuGet package, as mentioned by previous reply.
- Replace the `graph.DrawString` line with the following code (although this is C#, sorry) to render the text using a MigraDoc `Paragraph` instance, using your existing `XGraphics` `graph` instance from PDFsharp.

  ```
  var document = new Document();
  var section = document.AddSection();
  var paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
  paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
  paragraph.Format.Font.Name = "Arial";
  paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 12;

  paragraph.AddText("Sample ");
  paragraph.AddFormattedText("Text", TextFormat.Bold);

  var docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(document);                            
  docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
  docRenderer.RenderObject(graph, XUnit.FromPoint(X), XUnit.FromPoint(Y), XUnit.FromPoint(700), paragraph);
  ```

Comment: Any way to know what is the resulting height of the rendered paragraph?  I need this to know where start draw the next one!

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `DrawString` for the regular part, then invoke `DrawString` for the bold part, then invoke `DrawString` for the next regular part. Always give the correct position for each string.

You can look at the `XTextFormatter` class. It implements automatic linebreaks, but does not support mixing different font styles yet. It can get you started.

Pro tip: You can get MigraDoc and PDFsharp in one NuGet package. MigraDoc allows mixing in a single paragraph, handles linebreaks and pagebreaks automatically and also brings other benefits like page headers and footers.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid having to do the double DrawString method, but I'll look into the MigraDoc/PDFSharp fusion. Thanks!